# How to access a relative path from flashdrive?

Tags: javascript, html, path

i want to access a .html from pendrive but when i give a absolute path, the functionalities of that .html doesn't work. Only I can see that .html page with nothing working. The code is in javascript.

The .html file is in a directory in a pendrive. I am accessing it as:-

**Commands: --url file:///mnt/pendrive_name/folder1/folder2/folder3/index.html**

So when I access this, functionalities are not working because it is a absolute path.

Comment: You're trying to access the .html file from where? And to do what with?

Comment: .html file is in a directory in a pendrive. I am accessing it as:-

file:///mnt/pendrive_name/folder1/folder2/folder3/index.html

So when I access this, functionalities are not working because it is a absolute path.

Comment: That answers neither of my questions. Read them again.